# When editing from the Review Queue there is no way to see the question, nor any link to the question or answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

If you open the review queue; then edit an answer;  you can neither see the question any more nor do you have any link to the question or answer to e.g. load it in a new tab, you have to edit the answer from memory.  This makes non-trivial edits difficult especially if you need to refer to variable names, or copy code from the question into the answer etc.

For consistency with the normal editing process I think it should leave the question on the screen when you start editing. But at the very least a link to the question would be a great improvement.

Does anyone have a good workaround for this problem?

Comment: While I really want to have this feature implemented, the "normal editing process" may not be the proper term because [inline editing is a privilege of 2k](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350051/241919), and editing on a different page is the normal one.

Comment: I just drag the question link and then edit the answer. I don't find it a big deal.

Comment: Duplicate the tab (which will open the review without the edit in process) and use the link that's in that duplicate tab to get to the question/answer page.

Comment: Just to make sure you know: Editing from any review queue (the blue "Edit" button) removes the post from that queue. Only use the blue "Edit" button if your edit resolves *all* reasons the post is in that queue. Basically, it causes the system to treat the post as if everything's all right. If you want to make an edit that *doesn't resolve* the fundamental issues with the post, then, please, open the post in a new tab and perform the edit from the question/answer page, *not* from the review queue page. It's a pain, but that's [how the system works](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659)).

Comment: When you want to act, simply open question as if you would find it without review queue. The reviews are using convenient UI to let you quickly go through many questions, skipping the most. Inline editor similarly to inline tag edit is made for trivial edits, which are probably the majority. Btw, why do you want to copy code from question?

Comment: @sinatr someone answered with a single line of code and forgot to tell OP what to do with it!; i was editting it to say "replace $oldLineOfCode with $newLineOfCode"

Answer (score 9):

> you have to edit the answer from memory

Alternatively, you can open the full context in a new tab or window *first* and compare the post you are editing to that view.

That aside, Stack Overflow is currently [implementing/testing a review queue overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview) which is likely to include such features. If you think a feature like this is needed and is not mentioned already, you should suggest it on MSE at the link I provided.

Answer (score 5):

My (admittedly, not ideal) workaround is to copy the URL (of the *review item*) from the address bar, open a new tab, load that URL and from there link to the Q&A page (if necessary; sometimes, the review queue does show the question already).

Answer (score 1):

This is a real problem, if you need to look at the question after entering edit dialog my technique is to **Ctrl+C** the changes already made and click back (unless I've edited tags and title, in which case a new tab is needed). A scary proposition because you risk loosing the work you've already done.

Normal editor dialog lets you see the original thread under preview. For immersion I'm not sure if I wouldn't prefer a simple `open original post` link to open a new tab.

For folks who enjoy improving suggested edits the current layout is cumbersome.